# How to extend the_content of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a plugin which will pull custom meta post automatically.

For example if I have a post with content

```
"A post content"
```

when display content in the theme used the_content() tag, I want to display as :

```
A post content <br> <div id="custom-data">Some custom data</div>
```

In that way, I can build a plugin to pull custom meta post automatically and re-style the custom data.

Anyone know it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [add_filter()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to add text to the content. Here's an example:

```
function functionname($text){
     $text .= 'Some extra text, added below the content';
     return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'functionname');
```

There are many filters you can hook on, here's a list: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

Comment: Awesome! I noticed this function but I'm not focus so I can make it work like you. Thanks!